# Vuetify + Vuejs project add default or extra margin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, vuetify.js

I have a website which is developed with `vuetify 2.3.1` and it looks something like this:

[image]

today, when I open it again (without doing any change) I found it looks like that:
[image]

It looks like all the website just got an extra margin that comes from nowhere, and it is not only in this page but in the whole system. I opened it in the localhost environment and also in production and both have this change even though I didn't push anything to production.

I can't find out what the problem is. I tried to update my vuetify version but it didn't succeed. I hope you will have a solution for me because I'm lost.

Comment: I tried to add * { margin: 0 !important; } but it is not solves all the issues

Answer (score 0):

Some HTML elements come with default margins. If you would like to have full control over your padding, border and margins, recommendation would be to add a universal selector with `border-sizing` set to `border-box`, and set your body to have margin: 0. Here's more info, [link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```
* { 
    border-sizing: border-box;
  }

body { 
    margin: 0;
 }
```

Comment: I try to add it but unfortunately it didn't help. I want to believe that there is something wrong with one of the versions of my npm packages